# Pronoun after “should” to express a statement rather than a question

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is it possible to say:

> He decided the remainders should he relinquish.

It sounds more interrogative than declarative, putting the pronoun after "should" makes it sound like that to me.

Comment: Do you mean: "He decided the remainders should **be** relinquish**ed**"? Otherwise your sentence does not really make sense.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us more about this sentence. Without more details, we can't provide a useful answer. Please read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages, and also our [**Details, Please**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post. They will help you write a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you want this sentence to mean, so it's a somewhat difficult to answer. It's also unclear, but less important, what "remainders" means in this sentence. However, I can give you some options.

> He decided that he should relinquish the remainders.

This construction implies that his decision was to relinquish the remainders.

> He decided which remainders he should relinquish.

This construction suggests that his decision was about which of the remainders to relinquish, and which ones not to relinquish.

In neither case does it sound good to put "he" after "should". Usually, ending a sentence with the phrase "should he [verb]" is used in a subjunctive construction, which is somewhat uncommon in modern English:

> He decided to relinquish the remainders, should he return.

That means that he decided that, *if he returns*, he would then relinquish the remainders. The sentence you've given us is impossible to interpret as having a subjunctive clause at the end, so I would avoid the "should he [verb]" construction.

In any case, I'm assuming that "the remainders" is the object of the verb "relinquish". If that is not the case, then I have certainly misunderstood your intent, and I apologize.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this site and unsure of standards. Why the down vote?